# PHP replace string value from the specific position to the immediate first special character from the string

Tags: php

How to replace string value from the matching part in the specified string.

Exmaple,

```
$haystack = "2548: First Result|2547: Second Result|2550: Third Result|2551: Fourth Result
```

Now I want to change starting from **2547:** to the first **| (pipe)** after the starting value.

```
$result = "2548: First Result|2547: My New String|2550: Third Result|2551: Fourth Result
```

How can I replace the value of the Specific string from the **$haystack** variable.

**Want to replace value with first matching string to immediate first pipe character in PHP.**

In the given string, **2547: Second Result**| replace with **2547: My New Value|** and remaining part of the string as it is.

Is it possible without using Regular express in PHP and just use common function like **strpos()** or any other php string function or we can do it easily using **preg_replace()**.

Comment: Is the value you want to replace known? As in, do you only know the number `2547` or do you know the entire `2547: Second Result` value?

Comment: @El_Vanja I know the only start with number not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
$new_value = "My New String";
$array     = explode("|",$haystack);
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key)
    $new_array[] = (strstr($key,'2547:'))?"2547: ".$new_value:$key;

print_r(implode("|",$new_array));

/*
Output
2548: First Result|2547: My New String|2550: Third Result|2551: Fourth Result
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str_replace` if you know the full value you want to replace:

```
$find = "2547: Second Result";
$replace = "2547: My New Value";
$haystack = "2548: First Result|2547: Second Result|2550: Third Result|2551: Fourth Result";

$result = str_replace($find, $replace, $haystack);

print_r($result);
```

You can also use a loop :

```
$collection = [];

$find = "2547: Second Result";
$haystack = "2548: First Result|2547: Second Result|2550: Third Result|2551: Fourth Result";

$parts = explode('|', $haystack);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    [$id, $old_value] = explode(':', $part);

    if (strpos($find, $id) !== false) {
        $part = "{$id}: My New Value";
    }

    $collection[] = $part;
}

$result = implode('|', $collection);

print_r($result);
```

These are not the only ways to do this...

Comment: I know the only number that start with but not know exact string value.

Comment: ok my 2nd solution example with the loop will work int he case you don't have the full string and just the number